# Declaring list of a specefic type in F#

Tags: list, f#

Here I have this  simple binary search tree type:

```
type Tree<'k, 'v> =
    | EmptyTree
    | TreeNode of 'k * 'v * Tree<'k,'v> * Tree<'k,'v>
```

In C# if we have a class named Tree we can write

```
List<Tree> tree = new List<Tree>()
```

but how can I declare a list of type Tree in F#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your C# example, you are using a `Tree` type that is not generic - presumably, it is a type that contains a specific type of keys and values. In contrast, your F# `Tree<'k, 'v>` type is a generic type, meaning that if you want to use it, you have to specify what types you want to use as your keys and values.

This means that if you want to create a list of trees, you need to decide what the type of keys and values will be. The F# name for `List` is `ResizeArray`, so you could write something like:

```
let tree = new ResizeArray<Tree<string, int>>()
```

There are some cases where you can write code that is generic and does not need to specify the types. For example, you could write a function that creates a list of two singleton trees:

```
let twoSingletons k v = 
  let res = new ResizeArray<Tree<string, int>>() 
  res.Add(TreeNode(k, v, EmptyTree, EmptyTree))
  res.Add(TreeNode(k, v, EmptyTree, EmptyTree))
  res
```

Most often, you will not actually need to write code like this. If you use F# lists rather than `ResizeArray`, then you can use the `[ .. ]` notation to construct your list and you don't need to worry about specifying the types explicitly. The type inference takes care of that:

```
let twoSingletons k v = 
  [ TreeNode(k, v, EmptyTree, EmptyTree)
    TreeNode(k, v, EmptyTree, EmptyTree) ]
```